# The kernel is telling me that PCIe bandwidth is limited

Tags: pcie, bandwidth

From my kernel messages:

```
126.016 Gb/s available PCIe bandwidth, limited by 8.0 GT/s PCIe x16 link at 0000:16:00.0 (capable of 252.048 Gb/s with 16.0 GT/s PCIe x16 link)
```

My [Supermicro X11-SRM-F](https://www.supermicro.com/en/products/motherboard/X11SRM-F) has only one x16 PCIe 3.0 slot, which is used by an nVidia RTX 3070.

What is capping it at 8GT/s instead of 16GT/s speed?

*Ubuntu*: **20.10**

*Kernel*: **5.8.0-43-generic**

*GPU*: **nVidia GTX 3070**

***Update***: my other PC (core i5 Haswell) has an even more severe limit:

```
pci 0000:01:00.0: 32.000 Gb/s available PCIe bandwidth, limited by 2.5 GT/s PCIe x16 link at 0000:00:01.0 (capable of 126.016 Gb/s with 8.0 GT/s PCIe x16 link)
```

Comment: Did you ever find out what the problem is?

Comment: 2.5GT/s is PCIe 2.0 at half rate. I have a piece of junk motherboard, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your system/bridge doesn't support PCIe 4.0 which is 16GT/s. Your card supports PCIe 4 though...

`sudo lspci -vv -s 0000:16:00.0` should show you what the bridge is capable of. This will indicate a x16 link at 8.0GT/s.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think there is a bug in the kernel reporting message (I am facing strange messages like this myself)

```
2.5GT/s * 16 = 4Gb/s, not 32..... (these are approximate, I know 1Transfer != 1b)
```

I think what is happening is that you put your device in a PCIe x4 slot instead of a x16 slot. Read the motherboard manual to find which slot is the correct.